# Can I use conditional operations with v-model?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

What I am trying to achieve is a component that deals conditionally with new input or old input(edit). I've tried this, inspired by this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44431507/using-conditional-operators-in-v-model):

```
<input type="text" placeholder="New Event" v-model="event.title ? event.title : title" required/>
```

or even

```
<input type="text" placeholder="New Event" v-model="event.title || title" required/>
```

but both don't work. I get errors in the console.

`event.title` comes from prop `event`;

`title` is a property in the data object with the value of `''`.

In Vue 2 do I need to build 2 separate components? One for new input and another for editing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this one, it works for me :

```
  <td>
    <div v-if="event">
      <input v-model="event.title">
    </div>
    <div v-else><input v-model="title"></div>
  </td>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `computed` for this purpose like below :

```
<input type="text" placeholder="New Event" v-model="nameOfMethod" required/>
```

and within `computed` methods create `nameOfMethod` with your logic like this :

```
computed:{
    nameOfMethod(){
        if (this.event.title  === "")
            return this.title;
        else
            return this.event.title;
    },

}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work. The computed property would return the initial value of the input, but the input would not be able cause an update of the variable through `v-model`.

Comment: @tony19 what do you mean by "the input would not be able cause an update of the variable .. ?" if he passes `event.title`, I don't think he will update it anyway

Comment: The purpose of `v-model` is to allow two-way binding of a property. See [docs](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Basic-Usage).

Comment: @Thamerbelfkih I agreed with tony19 cz i tried it too before and it failed to work