# How do you conditional bind v-model in Vue?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vue.js

In JavaScript, object can optional spread value like this:

```js
const payload = {
  name: "Joseph",
  ...(isMember && { credential: true })
};
```

In React, JSX can optional pass props like this:

```
<Child {...(editable && { editable: editableOpts })} />
```

Now in Vue, how do I achieve optional `v-model`?

I have a textarea like this

```html
<template>
  <textarea v-model="textValue"> <!-- How can I optional bind v-model? -->
</template>
```

How can I achieve optional bind `v-model`?

I want to do this because I want to show warning on that textarea when error occurs.

When error occurs, textarea shows the warning and clear the input (the `v-model`)

Comment: Have you tried the conditional syntax from v-bind? v-model="{ vModelProperty: condition }" I don't know if it'll work, but it might

Comment: I want optional binding the v-model.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The correct way is to use the get and set properties of computed variable

```
<template>
  <textarea v-model="compVal" />
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      valueTrue: 'hello',
      valueFalse: 'bye',
      selected: false
    }
  },
  computed: {
    compVal: {
      get () {
        if (this.selected) {
          return this.valueTrue
        } else {
          return this.valueFalse
        }
      },
      set (val) {
        if (this.selected) {
          this.valueTrue = val
        } else {
          this.valueFalse = val
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: This is a life saving code. Thank you Dicren

Comment: I am only getting into getters and setters: When would one use the set property in this particular case?

Answer (score 2):

I think something like this would do the trick for you

```
<template>
  <textarea v-if="hasError" :value="textValue">
  <textarea v-else v-model="textValue">
</template>
```

Comment: I think this is the only way~

Comment: Except you need a wrapper div inside template.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `v-if` to check first condition, if matched then bind model like this

```
<template>
  <textarea v-if="something" :value="textValue">
  <textarea v-else v-model="textValue"> <!--  bind v-model here -->
</template>
```

Or you can use ternary operator like this

```
<textarea v-model="textValue == 'test' ? 'ifTrue' : 'ifFalse'">
```

For more refer this links

- https://forum.vuejs.org/t/conditional-v-model/17623
- https://forum.vuejs.org/t/v-model-with-conditional-binding-target/8718
- [Using conditional operators in v-model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44431507/using-conditional-operators-in-v-model)

Comment: Thank you, but in this way, it still binds the v-model.
I want optional binding.

Answer (score -2):

Didnt you try the ternary operator?

```
<template>
  <textarea v-model="someValue == 'test' ? 'value1' : 'value2'">
</template>
```

and in data:

```
data(){
   return {
      someValue: "test",
      value1: "i am value 1",
      value2: "i am value 2"
   }
}
```

Or you can do it with computed properties like this:

```
<template>
  <textarea v-model="myModel">
</template>

computed: {
   myModel(){
      if(this.someValue == "test"){
         return "value1";
      }else{
         return "value2";
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but in this way, it still binds the v-model.
I want optional binding.