# Vue - What is wrong with my v-model conditional that works fine in the template

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to enter a conditional for v-model but it is not working can someone please tell me what's wrong?

In the template I have the exact same conditional for value that must be displayed and that works, why is it not working for v-model.

Here is a button that displays the current rating and if there is no current rating it displays 0.

```
<button
    type="button"
    class="rateBtn"
    @click="showRating(post.id)"
>
    {{ post.rating == null ? 0 : post.rating[0] }}
</button>
```

The exact same ternary operator for the following v-model gives me an error:

```
VueCompilerError: v-model value must be a valid JavaScript member expression.
```

Here is the Vue part:

```
<div class="ratingStars">
    <div class="rating flex">
        <div
            class="star"
            v-for="index in stars"
            :key="index"
        >
            <input
                type="radio"
                name="stars"
                :value="index"
                v-model="
                    post.rating == null ? 0 : post.rating[0]
                "
                @change="ratePost"
            /><label>☆</label>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Because if the button shows 0 (there isn't any ratings yet) then I get an error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: post.rating is null
```

What is wrong with my v-model conditional please?

Comment: v-models shouldn't have conditionals, v-models are for linking/modeling variable value to html input element. What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: Ok well I read you can use a condition inside v-model https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60703994/how-do-you-conditional-bind-v-model-in-vue . As I said in my question if I do not have a condition for post.rating then I get an error post.rating is null. I still want to display the form for someone to vote for a post so I cannot do a v-if on the form otherwise it will not show

Comment: that question has computed get/set, do you? can you provide relevant code

Comment: Ok that is just one there are others https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44431507/using-conditional-operators-in-v-model that just have a conditional in the v-model. I do not have a computed get/set for that value. The problem is there are many posts on the page each having its own rating so really not sure how to handle a computed get/set with that

Comment: did you read the answer on that one `can't give v-model a string like you're attempting in your example.` or the second one where it's tied to `value` not v-model

Comment: yes, think about when the ternary is true, it simplifies to `v-model="0"` which is not valid.  v-model must always bind itself to a variable of some sort